# How to upload and insert multiple images with form input in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

controller:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = explode(".", $filename);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $array = array("jpg","jpeg","png");
    $PATH = "public/images/users/";
    if(in_array($ext,$array)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],  $PATH.$newfilename)){
            $data = array(
                "name" => $this->input->post('name'),
                "image_gallery" => $newfilename
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('product',$data);
        }else{
            echo $this->lang->line('notUpload');
        }
    }else{
        echo $this->lang->line('extNotMatch');
    }
}
```

view:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="card m-0">
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple/>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this code I have simply create a form and want to insert form data along with multiple images but I have got an error

> Message: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

and

> Message: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

and I also want to `change name of uploaded image`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller code as below:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $total = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
        $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $temp = explode(".", $filename);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $array = array("jpg","jpeg","png");
        $PATH = "public/images/users/";
        if(in_array($ext,$array)){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],  $PATH.$newfilename)){
                $data = array(
                    "name" => $this->input->post('name'),
                    "image_gallery" => $newfilename
                );
                $insert = $this->db->insert('product',$data);
            }else{
                echo $this->lang->line('notUpload');
            }
        }else{
             echo $this->lang->line('extNotMatch');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change? Why was OP's code not working?

Comment: When you use the "multiple" attribute with file input, you get the result in an array. I have only added a loop to iterate and save one file at a time.

Comment: it work but when I submit form only one image upload into a folder and it insert multiple image that means if I select 2 images then two rows created I want to upload multiple images with singal row like `img1.jpg, img2.jpg`.

Comment: Do you need comma-separated filenames in the image_gallery field?

Answer (score 0):

`explode` will take a string and use the `delimiter` argument to split into pieces. In the original, because you are using `multiple` to allow multiple files `$_FILES['file']['name']` becomes an array in it's own right. The same issue affected the `pathinfo` call so you need to use a different syntax to access the file data. If you create the variables at the beginning of the loop you can avoid such issues.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES[ $fieldname ] ) ){

    $errors=array();

    $allowed=array( "jpg", "jpeg", "png" );
    $path='public/images/users/';
    $fullpath=__DIR__ . '/' . $path;

    $fieldname='file';


    # multiple files require a slightly odd syntax to access each file
    foreach( $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['name'] as $i => $void ) {

        if( !empty( $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {
            $name = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['name'][$i];
            $size = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['size'][$i];
            $type = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['type'][$i];
            $tmp  = $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['tmp_name'][$i];
            $error= $_FILES[ $fieldname ]['error'][$i];

            $ext  = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $tmp );
            /*
                other tests - check mime type? size?
            */


            if( in_array( $ext, $allowed ) ){
                /*
                    using the full path rather than a relative path
                    is, in my opinion, more reliable - hence __DIR__
                */
                $filename=sprintf('%s.%s',round(microtime(true)),$ext);
                $filepath=sprintf('%s%s',$fullpath,$filename);
                $displaypath=sprintf('%s%s',$path,$filename);

                $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $filepath );
                if( $status ){
                    $data=[
                        'name'          =>  $this->input->post('name'),
                        'image_gallery' =>  $displaypath
                    ];
                    $insert = $this->db->insert('product',$data);

                }else{
                    $errors[$name][]=$this->lang->line('notUpload');
                }
            }else{
                $errors[$name][]=$this->lang->line('extNotMatch');
            }
        }
    }
    if( !empty( $errors ) ){
        foreach($errors as $name => $arr){
            printf('<h1>%s</h1><pre>%s</pre>',$name,print_r($arr,true));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it give a line number? In the above there is a defined `$fieldname` variable before the loop